# string variable returning as double

Tags: string, parsing, double, stringtokenizer

Create a method called parseEqn which will receive 1 String variable and return the double value of the expression passed to it.

```
parseEqn("123+23") → 146.0
parseEqn("3+5") → 8.0
parseEqn("3-5") → -2.0
```

so thats the question^^^^ and i think what i need to do is first use a string tokenizer to split the string up and then convert the tokens into doubles and from there add or subtract depending on the operator...but im not sure..

this is what i have so far

```
public double parseEqn(String str) {

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "+-", true);


String first= st.nextToken();
String op= st.nextToken();
String second= st.nextToken();

 double num1 = Double.parseDouble(first);

  double num2 = Double.parseDouble(second);

if (op.equals("+")){
 return num1+num2;
} 
else (op.equals("-")){
 return num1-num2;
}
```

i have no clue though....

Answer (score 0):

Writing an expression parser is not a trivial task. The standard algorithm for parsing arbitrary infix expressions is the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). The idea is to run through each token and build a Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) expression from the input. An RPN expression is essentially a stack-based list of operations that is very easy for a computer to work with (and easy to write code to evaluate).